# set up MVC .NET application with Azure Connected Services

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-active-directory, connected-services

What we are trying to do is set up our MVC .NET application with Azure Connected Services within Visual Studio. We are trying to connect to the Existing Azure AD Application. We have the correct domain selected, and also the correct redirect URI


[image]


We need to be able to read directory data to determine user group but we don’t have client secret


[image]
This is the error we get


[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your existing Azure AD application is registered as:

**Accounts in this organizational directory only (Devchat only - Single tenant)** or **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**.

Other types are not supported to be updated in this case.

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) to register an application for a quick test.